# Has anyone run their game on Higher Resolution in Cocos2d-android?

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android

**CCScene doesn't show anything on higher resolution ?**

I am working on a project in which I'm using the cocos2d_android.jar and on the 4.3 version the screen goes blank and music/ccTouches/others things working fine.

Even after I change the jar file with the API level 18(4.3 version), Add into my project and there is no error in the import time and uses their classes  but in the **RunTimeError occurred like :**

```
09-14 07:49:49.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1282): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 102
09-14 07:49:49.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1282): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-14 07:49:49.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1282):     at      org.cocos2d.nodes.CCAtlasNode.calculateMaxItems(CCAtlasNode.java:86)
09-14 07:49:49.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1282):     at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCAtlasNode.<init>(CCAtlasNode.java:80)
09-14 07:49:49.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1282):     at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCLabelAtlas.<init>(CCLabelAtlas.java:41)
09-14 07:49:49.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1282):     at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCLabelAtlas.label(CCLabelAtlas.java:36)
09-14 07:49:49.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1282):     at   org.cocos2d.nodes.CCDirector.setGLDefaultValues(CCDirector.java:600)
```

**EDIT 3:**

**These error comes when I change API level 18 in the Cocos2d-android main Library But What I found after this that the issue is not belongs to the  API level 17/18 than I changed the library as previous AND ISSUE is relate to the HIGH RESOLUTION**

I debugged the project but couldn't sort out this problem.

**EDIT 1:**

***I checked two game which is made through cocos2d-android.jar and The same thing happened in one game like CCScene doesn't display anything  and another one is working fine.***

**Edit 2 :**

**Nexus 7 resolution 1280*1920 and The height is acceptable after many changes in screensize what I found is 1735 is maximum height take by cocos2d-android.                *Is there any way to increase the size of height***

What is the possibility to make it working. Somebody suggest the way

Comment: focus on the EDIT 2 "

Answer (score 1):

With Android version 4.3 came some core changes and a couple of bugs. Google patched up 4.3 about a week after release. Are you testing on a Nexus device with the latest (and updated) 4.3 version?

Comment: yeah , I am using nexus 7 (4.3)

Comment: what is the solution for this ?

Comment: It's hard to tell if there is any direct solution. As I said before 4.3 brought lots of bugs.

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/35255

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58385

Hopefully the authors of Cocos2d might come out with a fix soon,
or Google them self will update 4.3.

Comment: I found two game on google play which include the cocos2d android library. One game has same problem what I'm facing but the another one run perfectly on 4.3

Comment: So , I think May be there is another issue effected not this

Comment: i see some nullpointer exception there. try running your game in debug mode with breakpoints.

Comment: that issue comes in the library when I change the library API level 17 to 18. But what I found after is "the issue belongs to the high resolution." @sandeep

Comment: please read the "Edit 2" , May be you'll get the point ? @sandeep

Answer (score 1):

Solution : to this problem is

change gluPerspective to use 1662 instead of 1500 in CCDirector(setProjection method). This will work with resolutions up to 1920 galaxy s4 etc.